# Safest place to park a spaceship close to the Sun

Tags: astronomy

Suppose that I have a spherical space-ship with an approximately 1 kilometer diameter.
For some reason I need to park it (unmanned) for a long period (100+ years) fairly close to the Sun. (Half the distance between Sun and Mercury. But the ship doesn't have to be in the same plane as the Sun/Mercury.)

I'm concerned about heat received from the Sun and of course all other radiation. To more it gets the better its shielding/cooling needs to be.

The ship is kept stationary in a fixed position. It doesn't orbit around the Sun. (It has maneuvering capability to keep in place.) The ship can rotate itself any way it wants to spread exposure evenly over its entire hull if needed.

What would be the safest place to park the ship ? I'm guessing above one of the poles would probably expose it to the least radiation/heat, but I really don't know for sure.

Comment: Why do you need it to not be orbiting around the sun? If that's just a requirement for your story that's fine, but orbiting would make the task a lot easier. (capture an asteroid / make a sheet of metal to block the radiation, put it in orbit and stay in it's shadow)

Comment: @Lacklub Yes, it is a story requirement. The ship must remain in fixed position regarding the Sun and the galactic center. Plot has cryptic message that describes where to find the ship in terms of those reference points.

Comment: The non-orbiting thing is an awfully contrived plot device. Seriously reconsider it, because that's akin to asking how to park a helicopter for 100 years hovering above a volcano crater. The volcano is a kind of a problem that can be overcome by various technical measures. Keeping the helicopter hovering for 100 years is plainly impossible though. And given orbital elements everyone with a pinch of astronomy knowledge can determine the position of any body in space - seven parameters provide the unique identifier of the position in space at any given time, so the fact "it's moving" is moot.

Comment: Your best bet would be using lagrange points, since at least they stay mostly immobile in regards to a planet. Immobility in regards to the sun would take immense amounts of impulse.

Comment: On several answer comments you have pointed out that the "why isn't it orbiting" question is "part of the mystery."  WHy isn't "how does it deal with heating" not part of the mystery as well?  By analogy, it's like saying "the fact that we have cars which can drive around at 65mph is part of the mystery... but I really want to know how they mill metal into the shape of a key to start the car with."  By the time you can make a car, making a key is easy!

Comment: @SF I agree. It certainly doesn't demand any sort of reality check tag.

Comment: @CortAmmon: It's worse. Anything we come up with as a cooling system for the craft will be 21st century technology. Meanwhile, the craft's 'hover mode' is at least two centuries away from now. The technological gap would be quite glaring. It's like installing a Ferrari engine in a horse-drawn carriage and trying to invent the windshield to keep insects from falling into the coachman's eyes. I mean - maybe someone took the engine from a crashed UFO and installed it on a Soyuz, but that's this level of contrived.

Comment: *What would be the safest place to park the ship ?* - sure, on night side of the sun.

Comment: @SF. Hovering a helicopter over a volcano with a *surface gravity 28 times that of earth.* Granted, you have a little bit of range on your side, but hovering over a star with zero orbital velocity is going to require well over 1G of acceleration.

Comment: @UIDAlexD: It's not that bad - we have 1/r^2 in the gravitational force equation on our side. The gravitational acceleration at 30mln km (a bit over half Mercury's orbit) would be merely of order of 15cm/s^2. Not so bad. Though not only orbital speed to lose would be humungous, delta-V to remain hovering for 100 years at that acceleration is about 1.6c

Comment: @SF. Thank you, I didn't know how to calculate gravity at a given distance from a body. Using the dV Figure you just gave me I've calculated that the spacecraft - using an impossibly powerful reaction drive with an exhaust velocity of 99% c  - would need slightly over 80% of its mass to be propellant. Statites seem like the way to go.

Comment: @UIDAlexD: I didn't remember that off top of my head but wolframalpha.com is a wondrous tool.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: Don't worry, your ship can handle this.**

**Where are the dangers:**

Sunspots, solar flares and coronal mass ejections all occur 
[most frequently around the equator of the sun](http://www.space.com/11506-space-weather-sunspots-solar-flares-coronal-mass-ejections.html). It would therefore be preferable to park a ship near the poles. In practice, one would use a polar orbit which only visits the equator for short periods of time.

**But what is the potential damage?**

- Heat: The planet mercury gets really hot on the side facing the sun, but also cold on the side facing away. It averages out to about 130C, well within the specs of high-temperature electronics. If your ship rotates, that's about the temperature to expect, though the actual temperature of an object in space is a complicated question best suited for the space stackexchange.
- Radiation: If a satellite suffers a coronal mass ejection, it is not like a plane in a storm. The solar wind is not a gust that will blow the satellite off course. What's happening is that the satellite is being peppered by charged particles, so that the satellite itself becomes charged. We're talking static electricity, the kind you experience when shuffling your feet on a carpet. Just like you can experience a jolt when being charged in this way, the satellite can short-circuit itself. To avoid this, your space-ship could have an ion motor or something similar which expels charged particles. It can then safely lower its own charge.

**Conclusion:**

You can safely describe a ship which will handle what the sun throws at it. What's really breaking the suspension of disbelief however, is stating that the ship actively keeps itself in a fixed position, for a hundred years. If you instead put it in an orbit, it sounds a lot more natural to the reader.

Comment: Natural has little to do with the positioning. I never said humans put it there, did I? It sort of acts as the monolith from 2001. It provides a riddle which humanity needs to solve to prove it is ready for First Contact.

Comment: @Tonny What he means is that the plausibility of a craft not-orbiting, by maneuvering to oppose gravity, is far far far less plausable than the heating issues.  Any society sufficiently advanced to have that non-orbiting technology could *easily* conquer the heating issues before their morning coffee got cold.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the requirement to maintain a stable position near the Sun, and some additional factors mentioned in other answers like avoiding sunspots, flares and coronal mass ejection, your best bet would be to suspend the ship under a large enough solar sail to "hover" under the pressure of the sunlight. [Robert L Forward](https://infogalactic.com/info/Robert_L._Forward) invented such a device under the name "[Statite](https://infogalactic.com/info/Statite)"

[image]

*Statite in a halo orbit over Earth*

Because the Statite balances the thrust of the solar sail against the gravitational pull of the object, it is fairly obvious that the object will either be extremely lightweight, or the statite sail will have to be quite large. There are some calculations of a Dyson Swarm made from Statites surrounding the sun which might only total the mass of a single asteroid.

This would suggest that the alien spacecraft is a featherweight assembly of graphine, aerogels and similar materials. If that is the case, it would reach equilibrium temperature rather quickly, although there might be the problem of the graphine simply evaporating under the intense sunlight. This could be addressed by embedding heat pipes as part of the spaceship apparatus and having the pipes extend through the Statite's rigging to emerge in the shadowed side, where heat could be radiated away.

Any exploration team attempting to reach the object would be advised to use a Statite of their own, since matching orbits in the usual manner is not going to be possible. The exploration team's spaceship would need to manoeuvre into the proper orbital plane, deploy a solar sail of its own (or be powered by a solar sail in the first place), then hover close enough to the object for exploration teams and robots to transfer between the two ships. The exploration she is going to need to take the same factors of solar flux, mass to thrust ratio and heat loading into account as used by the ship already in place.

Comment: Expulsion of heat from the other side would push the craft towards the sun with the same speed it is pushed away from the sun. You need to reflect incoming energy to stay in balance.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu solar sails usually means reflective surface, however your statement not true because heat is emitted equally from both sides, light comes from only one side(for thin surface). difference between full reflection and full absorption is 2 times of trust, but it is not 0 in any situation.

Answer (score 1):

As Mołot says, location is irrelevant. The thing I'd raise in addition is that once a temperature equilibrium is reached, you'll stress the ship less by keeping the same side facing the sun at all times, as the expansion and contraction caused by heating and cooling will likely do more damage than just heating.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter

As far as we know, there is nothing of any significant size between Sun and Mercury, so nothing to hide behind. Sun is also pretty uniform. And corona is so chaotic, that small statistical differences (if any - couldn't find) aren't really important.

Comment: yes it does. if your orbit is too inclined, you may experience rapid magnetic flux through your ship, which would slow its orbit down, and send it crashing into the star.

Comment: @tuskiomi when I answered, ship was supposed **not** to orbit Sun. Without orbit there is no inclination and your argument is void.

Comment: then it does matter even more! park it near a nice cold sun spot. move it around when new ones appear and old ones disappear!

Comment: @tuskiomi as asked, it was supposed to stay, immobile and unmaintained, for hundreds of years. Moving things OP wants to be immobile doesn't sound like a good answer to me. Feel free to post your own, of course.

Comment: You're way off course, here. the point is, it *does* matter where you put the station.

Comment: @tuskiomi How? Unless you can predict Sun's activity for hundreds of years, no matter what spot - ship must be able to survive pretty much anything that can happen ad this distance. Now it's over a cold spot. But who know what this part will be in a year, two, ten, hundred?

Comment: If a tree falls in the woods...

Answer (score 0):

Any ship which can maintain a stationary position halfway between mercury and the sun for 100 years+ will have no obvious problems handling the heat, since the technology required is fabulous. In effect, the ship must produce thrust equal to (roughly) 1/1000 the weight of the ship on earth. While this doesn't seem like much, over 100 years that's an enormous amount of energy, something like 1% of the ship's mass - assuming perfect energy conversion and a photon drive. For anything reasonable in terms of density radiation pressure from the sun doesn't help, either. Anything which can produce this amount of energy should have no trouble handling a little heat.

Furthermore, I assume your story calls for a visit to the enigma. You might want to think about this. The orbital velocity of Mercury is about 47 km/sec, so the nominal orbital velocity at the monolith's orbit is about 4 times that, call it 200 km/sec.

EDIT - As MobOrg pointed out, the factor is about square root of 2, not 4, so the orbital velocity will be about 66 km/sec. Sorry. Brain fart. END EDIT

While you may object that the object is not, in fact orbiting the sun, the point is that any intrepid space explorers will be, and an approaching spaceship will require that amount of velocity change (called delta-v) in order to dock with it, rather than going splat/crunch.  Note that this is about 20 times the velocity change required to get into low earth orbit from the surface of the earth, so no currently feasible technology is going to permit a visit.

Worse, in order to maintain its position, the object clearly needs a powerful anti-meteor defense, since anything in orbit around the sun will also be running 200 km/sec relative to the object, and any automated system is likely to lock onto your approaching ship, since it needs to get fairly close before it initiates a hi-g burn (to do otherwise requires much more fuel).

Comment: The visit to the enigma (and the tech needed for that) is indeed a major part of the whole story. I didn't want to make it too easy :-)

Comment: I agree with the first half about the energy needs of the ship.  The second half, though--if we **really** had to get there we could probably do it today.  The engine is a fusion variant on Orion and it's a one-way trip.

Comment: *The orbital velocity of Mercury is about 47 km/sec, so the nominal orbital velocity at the monolith's orbit is about 4 times that, call it 200 km/sec.* - it is not. Kepler 3th law : *The square of the orbital _period_ of a planet is directly proportional to the _cube_ of the semi-major axis of its orbit.*  - it will be 66km/s something like that.

Comment: @MolbOrg - You're right, of course. What was I thinking? I've edited. Thanks.